# What are the odds that every team that lost the prior week would be facing a team that won the prior week?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-theory

I apologize in advance for a potentially elementary question but I cannot figure out how to even begin with this.

- We have 10 teams
- Half lost the first week, the other half won
- Second week, we all face a different team

How would I calculate the odds of every 1-0 team facing an 0-1 team the 2nd week?

Answer (score 1):

To start you off.

You have 5 $A$ teams and 5 $B$ teams.  IF you wished to find the probability of randomly pairing them up into five pairs of $(A,B)$, then:

There are $10\choose 2,2,2,2,2$ ways to pair the teams off in total.

For the favoured case, line up the $A$ teams and count the ways to assign one $B$ team to each.  That's $5!$ ways.

$$\frac{5\choose 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}{10\choose 2,2,2,2,2} = \frac{5!\times 2!^5}{10!}$$

HOWEVER, this does not account for the condition that each A team must face a different B team than they did the week before.  Can you modify the above to do that?

Comment: Trying to go through this step by step. I read up on combinations but unsure what (10/(2,2,2,2,2)) mean. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @BelminFernandez It is a **multinomial coefficient**. ${10\choose 2,2,2,2,2}=\frac{10!}{2!2!2!2!2!}$.  ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem )